# do_action passing a variable with T_OBJECT_OPERATOR(->) PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a plugin that uses a custom checkout form. In this checkout form there is a "create account" checkbox identical to the default Wordpress one. I am trying to write some code to add another checkbox that allows the user to choose a role for this new account. The plugin that creates this checkout form has a do_action that I want to hook into. It even has a variable that I need. Sadly, I'm uncertain how to use this.

The do_action:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', $woocommerce_checkout->posted );
```

As you can see this uses `$woocommerce_checkout->posted`

My code has the following

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'validate_professional_field' 10,1);
```

And In my function I try to use this with the following code:

```
function validate_professional_field( $woocommerce_checkout->posted ) {}
```

This does not work And I have no clue what to do here..
How can I use the variables sent with the action?

In the end I want to use `$woocommerce_checkout->posted['createprofessional']` to get the value that should be the value of my checkbox.

**Other details**

This checkbox was made with the following code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_registration_form' , 'define_telesales_fields', 3);

<?php function define_telesales_fields() { ?>
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide create-professional">
        <div class="create-account">
        <input class="input-checkbox" id="createprofessional" type="checkbox" name="createprofessional" value="1" />
        <label for="createprofessional" class="checkbox"><?php _e( 'Create a professional', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
        </div>
    </p>          
<?php }?>
```

**Solved**

A comma was missing in the add_action

`add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'validate_professional_field', 10,1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `$woocommerce_checkout` as the parameter name in the function declaration; if you're passing the whole object into the function, you can then use `$woocommerce_checkout->posted` within the function itself.

eg:

```
function validate_professional_field( $woocommerce_checkout ) {
    //$woocommerce_checkout->posted is valid here
}

//and you'd call it like this:
validate_professional_field( $woocommerce_checkout );
```

Alternatively, if you know you only want to use `posted` in the function, you could limit the argument to just that, which seems to be what you want to do. In this case, give it a valid variable name in the function declaration, like so:

```
function validate_professional_field( $posted ) {
    //$posted is valid here, and will be contain the data from $woocommerce_checkout->posted that you're passing into the function.
}

//and you'd call it like this:
validate_professional_field( $woocommerce_checkout->posted );
```

Comment: Turns out I made a mistake in: `add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'validate_professional_field' 10,1);` it should be: `add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'validate_professional_field', 10,1);` But thank you very much for you effort. Thanks to your answer I knew if what I was doing was right. Not deleting the question as I think this maybe be useful to someone.